# Inserting duration longer than an hour into another table hour-by-hour

Tags: mysql

Please be patient, my english is not perfect

I have set up a mysql table to aggregate logs into it:

```
create table logs(
id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
player_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`in` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`out` DATETIME NOT NULL,
channel_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
frame_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
media_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

i use timediff between `in` and `out` to find out for how long the file was playing and when it started playing.
It became kind of large, so i decided to aggregate needed info into new table:

```
create table reports(
id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
year SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
month TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
day TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
hour TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
player_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
channel_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
frame_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
media_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
count MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
duration MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

i use following query to fill in the reports table:

```
insert into reports (year, month, day, hour, player_id, media_id, channel_id, frame_id, count, duration)
select year(logs.in), month(logs.in) as Month, day(logs.in) as Day, hour(logs.in) as Hour, logs.player_id, logs.media_id, logs.channel_id, logs.frame_id, count(logs.media_id) as Count, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(logs.out, logs.in))) as Duration 
FROM logs
where (logs.player_id=1 OR logs.player_id=2)
GROUP BY year(logs.in), month(logs.in), day(logs.in), hour(logs.in), player_id, media_id, channel_id, frame_id;
```

It works OK if timediff is less than an hour. But one media can play for much more than for several minutes:

```
+-------+------+------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------------------+--------------+
| Month | Day  | Hour | player_id | channel_id | frame_id | media_id | count(logs.media_id) | Duration     |
+-------+------+------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------------------+--------------+
|     6 |   19 |   14 |         5 |          4 |       18 |       54 |                    1 | 275h 48m 24s |
|     6 |   20 |    8 |         4 |          3 |       18 |       54 |                    1 | 78h 45m 28s  |
```

So if i check whether the file was playing on on player_id 5 on June, 20th my query would show me it wasn't, though it was. What i want to achive is filling my reports table like:

```
+-------+------+------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------------------+--------------+
| Month | Day  | Hour | player_id | channel_id | frame_id | media_id | count(logs.media_id) | Duration     |
+-------+------+------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------------------+--------------+
|     6 |   19 |   14 |         5 |          4 |       18 |       54 |                    1 |      48m 24s |
|     6 |   19 |   15 |         5 |          4 |       18 |       54 |                    1 |  1h  00m 00s |
|     6 |   19 |   16 |         5 |          4 |       18 |       54 |                    1 |  1h  00m 00s |
```

Is there a way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i've found a sollution. First i have to create a table with time ranges. I use a stored procedure for convinience

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `make_intervals`(startdate 
timestamp, enddate timestamp, intval integer, unitval varchar(10))
BEGIN
   declare thisDate timestamp;
   declare nextDate timestamp;
   set thisDate = startdate;
   drop temporary table if exists time_intervals;
   create temporary table if not exists time_intervals
  (
  interval_start timestamp,
  interval_end timestamp
  );
   repeat
      select
         case unitval
            when 'MICROSECOND' then timestampadd
 (MICROSECOND, intval, thisDate)
            when 'SECOND'      then timestampadd(SECOND, intval, thisDate)
            when 'MINUTE'      then timestampadd(MINUTE, intval, thisDate)
            when 'HOUR'        then timestampadd(HOUR, intval, thisDate)
            when 'DAY'         then timestampadd(DAY, intval, thisDate)
            when 'WEEK'        then timestampadd(WEEK, intval, thisDate)
            when 'MONTH'       then timestampadd(MONTH, intval, thisDate)
            when 'QUARTER'     then timestampadd(QUARTER, intval, thisDate)
            when 'YEAR'        then timestampadd(YEAR, intval, thisDate)
         end into nextDate;
  insert into time_intervals select thisDate, timestampadd(MICROSECOND, -1, nextDate);
  set thisDate = nextDate;
   until thisDate >= enddate
   end repeat;

 END
```

Then i process my main table against this temp table

```
SELECT DATE(time_intervals.interval_start) AS Date, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time_intervals.interval_start) AS Hour, player_id, channel_id, frame_id, media_id, count(media_id),
      sum(CASE 
          WHEN time_intervals.interval_start > TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(logs.in), DATE(logs.in)) 
    AND time_intervals.interval_start < TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(logs.out), DATE(logs.out))
    THEN 3600
WHEN time_intervals.interval_start = TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(logs.in), DATE(logs.in)) 
AND time_intervals.interval_start < TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(logs.out), DATE(logs.out))
THEN 3600 - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM logs.in)*60 - EXTRACT(SECOND FROM logs.in)
 WHEN time_intervals.interval_start = TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(logs.out), DATE(logs.out))
AND time_intervals.interval_start > TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(logs.in), DATE(logs.in)) 
THEN EXTRACT(SECOND FROM logs.out) + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM logs.out)*60 
WHEN time_intervals.interval_start = TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(logs.in), DATE(logs.in)) 
AND time_intervals.interval_start = TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(logs.out), DATE(logs.out))
THEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM logs.out)*60 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM logs.out) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM logs.in)*60 - EXTRACT(SECOND FROM logs.in)
 ELSE 0
 END) AS duration 
FROM time_intervals
LEFT JOIN logs 
Force index(media_id, player_id, channel_id, frame_id)
  ON time_intervals.interval_start >= TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(logs.in), DATE(logs.in)) 
    AND time_intervals.interval_start <= TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,HOUR(logs.out), DATE(logs.out))
    GROUP BY media_id, player_id, date, hour, channel_id, frame_id;
```

takes a while to process, especially with billions of rows, like in my case, but works.